# How to open a page in phonegap when a notification comes and user touch it?

Tags: android, cordova, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I have an app which receives notifications (people calling drivers services) and I want when a notification comes and user clicks (touch) on to open the app also open a specific page (which is in jQuery Mobile) to show info about who is calling.

I am using GCMPlugin.java to receive and using gcm-server.jar (with json_simple-1.1.jar) as the server sender.

I noticed when a notification comes this method is called in plugin class:
**sendJavascript(JSONObject _json)**

How can use this to open what I need in phonegap page?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code for this plugin it appears that when you make the JS call to create a notification you can pass a parameter that is a callback function.

From their code:

```
[{ senderID: senderID, ecb : eventCallback }]);
//Passing a list of arguments to the plugin
// The ecb variable is the STRING name of your javascript routine to be used for callbacks
```

Using this, if you have a function named eventCallback, it seems that function would be called after the notification was opened.

psudocode Example:

```
GCM.register('YOUR_SENDER_ID',eventCallback);

function eventCallback() {
  load.('SOME_PAGE');
}
```

Comment: source reference: https://github.com/marknutter/GCM-Cordova/blob/master/assets/www/GCMPlugin.js

Comment: But I don't want to do anything on the register action, that's working fine, what I want is when the notification is "clicked" and the app is opened use javascript to show a page with some info and some buttons to this user accepts or not the request (he is a driver).